# How to play sounds in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, audio

I am a beginner in this very confusing Objective-C game.

I would like to play a very short sound effect every time a certain button is pushed.

How can I do this?

Can I use an mp3 file?  Or will I have to convert to wav?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [System Sound Services](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html) to play short sounds:

```
CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
CFURLRef soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, CFSTR("filename"), CFSTR("aiff"), NULL);
SystemSoundID soundId;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundId);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId);
CFRelease(soundFileURLRef)
```

.caf, .aiff and .wav formats are supported.

Comment: Thanks, it compiles great.  I think I read that sound doesn't work on the simulator...  is this true?

Comment: Don't think so - simulator should be fine.

Comment: Okay, I've loaded this onto my iPhone and sound still does not work.  I've used both .wav and .aif file formats.  I've included "AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h."  Any ideas to make this work?

Comment: In order for it to work in the simulator, go to the System Prefs of your Mac and enable "Play user interface sound effects" in the "Sound Effects" section of the "Sound" preferences

Answer (score 1):

Not enough reputation to comment on the solution by @dstnbrkr so I'll post it as an answer instead.

In the above example, the `CFURLRef soundFileURLRef` isn't being released.

Call `CFRelease(soundFileURLRef)` after the last line (`AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundId);`) to release the Core Foundation object.